# SharePoint 2007 licensing - per server?

Tags: licensing

We are migrating our SharePoint 2007 farm to a data center which will use virtualised servers.

Does anyone know if the MOSS server (enterprise) license is per specific server, or if it can be transferred from one server to another?

I have had trouble finding references to this specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply per one server. You can move it to another server.

Comment: Thanks John. Do you know of any links I can use to add as a reference?

Comment: Not off hand. But in general, only OEM licensing (like Windows stickers on your workstation) are for a specific machine and cannot be transferred.